# Reg Exp in javascript for numbers and ':' only

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

How can I write a regular expression in javascript that checks a string for `^[0-9] + ':'` ?

Here is what I have so far: `new RegExp ('/^[0-9]+':'+$/')`

Thank you.

Comment: Can you give some examples of valid and invalid strings? Is `1::` valid? Is `123` valid? Is `:` valid? Is the empty string valid?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Include the colon in the [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html):

```
var regex = /^[0-9:]+$/;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to match in the cases where there are 1 or more numbers followed by a single colon, the proper regex would be

```
var regex = /^[0-9]+:$/;
```

If you wanted the match to include checking for the single-quotes then:

```
var regex = /^[0-9]+':'$/;
```

Caveats:

This is only going to match a line whose entire content is a series of numbers followed immediately by a colon.  If there can be spaces in the string, handling needs to be differently.  From the sound of the question and the general context, I'm assuming these are line numbers perhaps and as such you will have content following the colon.  If that's the case then remove the dollar sign ($) as such:

```
var regex = /^[0-9]+:/;
```

As other respondees pointed out, further clarification of appropriate results would assist in an answer.